# Codeigniter subtracting time and making an selection from database in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am building a library project where a user needs to know which books have not been submitted on time.So for that i have stored book_returning_date already in the database.However my issue here is that i need to know how to select the dates in model which have crossed there return date by comparing with today date.My model code is here as follow:

```
 public function timecalculations($table){
        $query= $this->db->get_where('issue_books',array('department_id'=>$table));
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and my controller is as here follows:

```
public function latebooks(){

        $this->load->model('Time');
        $id=$this->session->userdata('userid');
        $this->load->model('Department');
        $table=$this->Department->selecttable($id);
        foreach($table as $q){}
        $table = $q->department_name;
        $table = strtolower($table);
        $run=$this->Time->timecalculations($table);
        $this->load->view('Books/datetime',['query'=>$run]);
    }
```

I am new in codeigniter so please forgive as i may be having a little problem with the logic.Thanks in advance!

Comment: which CI version you are using

Comment: @RejoanulAlam codeigniter3

Comment: Can you tell us what issue/error you are facing ?

Comment: Your `foreach()` statment has no code in its curly brackets!

Answer (score 0):

add another where clause,

```
public function timecalculations($table){
    $this->db->where('book_returning_date < NOW()');
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    return $query->result();
}
```

this will return the rows where current date is already crossed book_returning_date
i am assuming u are saving the book_returning_date in the following format 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s'

Answer (score 0):

probably like this and sorry if i'm mistake
First need to Set Library Session setting in config 
for model :

```
    public function timecalculations($table){
        $condition = 'department_id = "'.$table.'"';
        $this->db->select('issue_books');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $query= $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

for controller i'm not sure but like this :

```
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->model('Time', 'time');
        $this->load->model('Department', 'departement');
        $this->load->library('Session');
    }

    public function latebooks($id){
        $id=$this->session->userdata('userid');
        $table=$this->department->selecttable($id);
        foreach($table as $q){ (probably i'm wrong)
            $table = $q->department_name; (probably i'm wrong)
        }   (probably i'm wrong)
        $table = strtolower($table); (probably i'm wrong)
        $run=$this->time->timecalculations($table);
        $this->load->view('Books/datetime',['query'=>$run]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public function timecalculations($table){
        $query= $this->db->where('book_returning_date < CURRENT_DATE()', NULL, FALSE)->get($table);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function latebooks()
{
    $this->load->model('Time');
    $this->load->model('Department');

    $id = $this->session->userdata('userid');    
    $result = $this->Department->selecttable($id);  # Changed 

    $table = $result[0]['department_name']; # Changed 
    $table = strtolower($table); # Changed 

    $run = $this->Time->timecalculations($table);
    $this->load->view('Books/datetime',['query'=>$run]);
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function timecalculations($table)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('issue_books',array('department_id'=>$table));
    $result =  $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```